# Connect to sqlite database - sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I tried to connect to my sqlite database `test.db`, but I get when I
try to access the content the following error message:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: testtbl2`, but I created
this table already and I can see it with phpLiteAdmin.
Thank you for helping me.

Here the Code I used:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python3


   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
   import time
   import sqlite3 
   import sys

   GPIO.setwarnings(False)
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
   GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)


   #Connection to Database
   conn = sqlite3.connect('/var/www/test.db')
   c = conn.cursor()
   c.execute('SELECT * FROM testtbl2')

   GPIO.cleanup()
```

Now I tried to create a database with the code below. My findings are: 
(I use a Rasperry Pi with Raspian)

1. A file named `test2.db` will be created, but it is not a sqlite-database file, rather than a normal and empty text file.
2. The file will be stored in the home folder and not as I needed in the folder `/var/www/`

What can I do to get a real database and to have the file in the right folder?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('test2.db')
c = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: have you done a commit after creation ?

Comment: No, because I created the table within phpLiteAdmin.

Comment: I used sqlite3 to access create database in ubuntu and there is no problem.

Comment: I tried this way as well (with commit after creation), but the result was the same. In this case the table was not visible within phpLiteAdmin, thus I expect that I'm not connected to the database.

Comment: I will try now again to create the database and table within the script. How can I check if it really worked?